# If template variable is null, hide it's nesting html element

Tags: python, html, django

Here's my template:

```
    <li><a href="/{{ user_settings.room2 }}" id="room2">/{{ user_settings.room2 }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="/{{ user_settings.room3 }}" id="room3">/{{ user_settings.room3 }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="/{{ user_settings.room4 }}" id="room4">/{{ user_settings.room4 }}</a></li>
```

If the value of `{{ user_settings.room2 }}` is null, hide its `<li>` parent. If the value of `{{ user_settings.room3 }}` is null, hide its `<li>` parent.

What is an efficient way this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an if statement in the template.

```
{% if user_settings.room2 %}
    <li><a href="/{{ user_settings.room2 }}" id="room2">/{{ user_settings.room2 }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your variable user_settings is a dictionary, you could use this to print only not empty items, but its almost the same thing as @leelum1 answer

```
    <ul>
    {% for key,value in user_settings.items %}
        {% if value %}
        <li><a href="/{{ value }}" id="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: `user_settings` is a model object - so the code you've given just shows nothing.